# React hooks scroll event performance issue

Tags: reactjs, touch, react-hooks

**Task:**

On touch devices get `.container.scrollLeft` and `transform: translateX` image depending on current horizontal scroll position. `.container` width bigger than its `.wrapper`.

Here you can check [live example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dry-bird-tmy89).

**Problem:**

Image moves but with an extremely low fps.

**Expected behavior:**

Fast and smooth movement.

**Detailed description:**

Thank you very much for reading this! I really get stacked with this issue. On desktop version, I'm just binding images position with `onMouseMove` events and everything is great. But with mobile version I tried `onTouch` events and native scroll event but nothing work as expected. I was looking for a solution or some working example and found nothing. So, here I am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this `useEffect` you're adding the scroll event listener on every render. So as it scrolls, it re-renders (as it should), but it re-adds the listener many times.

```
useEffect(() => {
    handleScroll();
    wrapperEl.current.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, {
      passive: true
    });
  });
```

It's far more efficient (and less likely to cause lumpy scrolling) to add the listener once on first render (using `[]` as the dependency array). You should also clean it up by returning a function that removes it on dismount:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const el = wrapperEl.current;
    el.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, {
      passive: true
    });
    return () => el.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);
```

This is probably enough to get things running smoothly. If not, then you can also throttle your `handleScroll` calls - there are many hooks-based examples available.

Comment: Now it is much better, thank you!

But I still have a problem with performance on some phones. When you scroll too fast background and images are loading through black squares. Can it be because of code warning about missing dependencies inside `useEffect`?

When you left dependency array empty it warns you about the missing `handleScroll`. But when you add this it warns that `handleScroll` was used before it was defined.

Anyway in most cases code is working but I guess it can be even better :)

I updated my demo here https://codesandbox.io/embed/dry-bird-tmy89